# Agregar Filtros de Búsqueda

Tags: php, javascript

Me gustaría saber como puedo hace un filtro avanzado para mi sistema[image: Filtros de Búsqueda]
Para que al momento de llenar uno o más input me aparezca la Tabla con el filtro que haya puesto y si no tiene ningún input con datos la tabla permanezca oculta, además el botón Añadir más filtros me abre un Modal en el cuál el usuario puede elegir más filtros para poder hacer una búsqueda más específica 
[image: Filtros para elegir]
En este Modal al seleccionar los checkbox que desee y darle clic en el botón agregar deberá agregar los inputs correspondientes, estoy desarrollando este filtro en PHP con MySQL y JavaScript, espero puedan ayudarme con esta duda que tengo.

Comment: Y cómo está implementado tu formulario? Recuerda que las preguntas aquí se enfocan en problemas de programación y darte una respuesta que sirva es difícil si no sabemos cuál es tu código. Añádelo ***como texto***

Comment: Las preguntas del tipo: "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato de preguntas y respuestas del sitio. 
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta cuanto antes.

Answer (score 0):

esto te podria ayudar aunque falta agregar la paginacion

https://www.phpzag.com/product-filter-search-with-ajax-php-mysql/

Saludos

Comment: Hola. Procura siempre complementar una respuesta centrada en un enlace externo, indicando algún breve ejemplo o ajustes relevantes que quien pregunta pueda hacer al código. Si el enlace se rome, tu respuesta ya no le va a servir al resto de la comunidad, ahora y en el futuro.